# Fix datalist single item layout while printing

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a datalist where i m displaying 8 items for printing.I m printing two items per row.When i print a two or more than two items,the layout is perfect.but when i print single item.the layout changes and expands.How Can i fix it for single item also.

```
       <asp:DataList ID="datalis1" runat="server"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal"   
                           BorderStyle="NotSet" CellPadding="0"   CellSpacing="5" RepeatLayout="Table"
                           RepeatColumns="2" >
                       <ItemStyle />
                    <ItemTemplate>

                     <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="boxdiv">

                        <table style="width: 94%;"  align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="table1">
                            <tr style="height:2px;">
                                <td  colspan="0" rowspan="0" height='2px'> 
                                 <asp:Label ID="lblwebsite"  runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text='<% # bind("website")%>'>
                                 </asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="height:2px;"    >
                                <td colspan="0" rowspan="0" height='2px'>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Call #">
                                    </asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblcontact" runat="server" Text='<% # bind("mobile1")%>'>
                                    </asp:Label> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Fax #">
                                    </asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblfax" runat="server" Text='<% # bind("fax")%>'>
                                    </asp:Label>
                                 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="height:2px;">
                                <td colspan="0" rowspan="0" height='2px' >
                                    <%--<asp:Label ID="lblfax0" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Address :">
                                    </asp:Label>--%>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbladdress" runat="server"    Text='<% # bind("address")%>'   ></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                          <tr style="height:4px;">
                          </tr> 
                          <tr style="height:4px;">
                          </tr> 
                          <tr style="height:2px;">
                              <td  height='2px'  >
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblfax1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Ord #">
                                    </asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblorder" runat="server" text='<% # bind("orderno")%>'>
                                    </asp:Label> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblfax2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Dt:">
                                    </asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblvrdate" runat="server" Text='<% # bind("vr_date")%>'>
                                    </asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr >
                              <td   height='2px' >
                                 <asp:Label ID="lblfax3" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Pt:">
                                 </asp:Label>
                                 <asp:Label ID="lblpt" runat="server"  Text='<% # bind("pname")%>'   Font-Bold="False" >
                                 </asp:Label> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                 <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Dr :">
                                 </asp:Label>
                                 <asp:Label ID="lbldrname"  Text='<% # bind("drname")%>'  runat="server" Font-Bold="False"  >
                                 </asp:Label>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                            <tr style="height:4px;"   >
                          </tr> 
                           <tr style="height:4px;"   >
                          </tr> 
                            <tr   >
                                <td   height='2px'>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
                                        Text="Rx:"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblorderSupplied" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Text='<% # bind("medicine")%>'    
                                        ></asp:Label> <br />
                                         <asp:Label ID="labeld" runat="server" Text="Qty:" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                                     <asp:Label ID="lblpack"  Text='<% # bind("pack")%>' runat="server"  ></asp:Label>   
                                            <asp:Label ID="txtmfgDt" runat="server"  text="x"> </asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblqty" runat="server" text='<% # bind("suppquantity")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                             <tr style="height:4px;"   >
                          </tr> 
                           <tr style="height:4px;"   >
                          </tr> 
                            <tr  >
                                <td  height='2px'>
                                   <%-- <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"     
                                        Text="Directions:"></asp:Label>--%>
                                        <%--  <div style="text-overflow : ellipsis; overflow: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; height:38px">--%>
                                         <asp:Label ID="lbldirections" Height="38PX"   Text='<% # bind("directions")%>' runat="server" Font-Bold="False"></asp:Label>
                                      <%--   </div>--%>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr  >
                                <td  height='2px'>                                            
                                <%--  <asp:Label ID="lblmfg" runat="server" text="Mfg:"></asp:Label>--%>
                                </td>
                            </tr>                                                              
                        </table>                            
                   </asp:Panel> 
                 </ItemTemplate> 


                   </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Show me your code , please !

Comment: The code is as above.when i select only single item the font size,line height etc automatically increases.